# Summing durations using Joda Time

Tags: java, android, jodatime, duration

I am trying to sum durations in the following format: "hh:mm:ss" (e.g.: "08:55:12") using Joda Time:

```
PeriodFormatter formatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
    .printZeroAlways().minimumPrintedDigits(2).appendHours()
        .appendLiteral(":").printZeroAlways().printZeroAlways()
            .minimumPrintedDigits(2).appendMinutes().appendLiteral(":")
                .printZeroAlways().minimumPrintedDigits(2).appendSeconds()
                    .toFormatter();
Duration totalTime = Duration.ZERO;


for (Entry entry : entries) {
    Period period = formatter.parsePeriod(entry.getTime());
    Duration duration = period.toStandardDuration();
    totalTime = totalTime.plus(duration);
}

Period totalPeriod = totalTime.toPeriod();
if (totalPeriod.getHours() < 10) {
    hours = "0" + totalPeriod.getHours();
} else {
    hours = Integer.toString(totalPeriod.getHours());
}
mTextView.setTextView(hours
    + String.format("%02d:%02d", totalPeriod.getMinutes(),
        totalPeriod.getSeconds()));
```

For some reason, it is giving me wrong results (summed durations is way too long). Can you help me find the cause of this problem?

Comment: Please give some example inputs, expected outputs and actual outputs. Providing us with a compilable self-contained example would also be helpful (and expected from a 2k+ user).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have just forgotten **a colon between hour-part and minute part** causing the total sum looking like 2701:44 instead of 27:01:44 (this is an example for the sum of the three elements "03:20:45", "00:40:11", "23:00:48" which is correctly calculated by Joda-Time).

So your solution should finally look like:

```
String output =
    hours + String.format(":%02d:%02d", totalPeriod.getMinutes(), totalPeriod.getSeconds());
System.out.println(output); // 27:01:44
```

But easier is just to **reuse your formatter object for printing**:

```
System.out.println(formatter.print(totalPeriod)); // 27:01:44
```

If you are interested in a pattern-based solution then check out my library Time4J with this example:

```
// input
String[] periods = { "03:20:45", "00:40:11", "23:00:48" };

// initialization
Duration.Formatter<ClockUnit> timeFormat = 
    Duration.Formatter.ofPattern(ClockUnit.class, "hh:mm:ss");
Duration<ClockUnit> dur = Duration.ofZero();

// calculate the sum
for (String entry : periods) { 
    dur = dur.plus(timeFormat.parse(entry));
}

dur = dur.with(Duration.STD_CLOCK_PERIOD); // normalization
System.out.println(timeFormat.format(dur)); // 27:01:44
```